# Assigning Raster Generated in Function as Global Variable with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

I am trying to write a script to be as robust as possible and am trying to assign a variable to each of my raster outputs (e.g. "winter") so that I may reference it many more times later in the script.

Since "winter" is being generated (and unsuccessfully assigned) within a function, I wanted to make it a global variable so that I can refer to it in the next function.

However, I'm receiving an error saying that my **local** variable is referenced before assignment and I don't understand why as I believe I am doing this in one of the lines of code below: `winter = outTimes.save("Winter")`

I am trying to keep my set up of generating these rasters within functons because I am running multiple similar functions and want to keep the variables that create the rasters local. (The raster outputs themselves are what I want to be global).

```
import arcpy

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.env.workspace = """C:\Users\inputData.gdb"""


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
anthro = arcpy.Raster("Anthro_Features")
conifer = arcpy.Raster("Conifer")
lek = arcpy.Raster("Lek")

def winterHabitat():
    # Multiply Rasters
    outTimes = anthro * conifer

    # Save the output
    global winter
    winter = outTimes.save("Winter")

winterHabitat()

# -------------------------------------------------------
# Pre-Breeding

def breeding():
    # Multiply Rasters
    outTimes = winter * lek

    # Save the output
    global Breeding
    Breeding = outTimes.save("Breeding")


breeding()
```

Comment: Use the keyword global https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/global.html but first declare winter = None outside the sub. If the variable name doesn't exist prior to the calling of the sub the global keyword has no effect..you should also be using global antrho and global conifer to indicate that the variables are global and not local. I notice your sub is not returning anything.. a sub should return *something* even if it is None.

Comment: Where are you declaring winter = None or global anthro/conifer?

Comment: @MichaelStimson Thanks. I'm putting winter = None right before the function (def winterHabitat()). Unfortunately, I'm getting the same error. It breaks at outTimes = winter * lek. I also tried winter = 0 instead of None.

Comment: In the winterHabitat sub shouldn't winter = outTimes? The outTimes.save() function doesn't return a raster, it returns None if successful therefore in breeding (which doesn't have a global winter statement) winter will be None. What is the variable lek?

Comment: Thank you @MichaelStimson! That worked. I ended up using:  winter = None
def winterHabitat():
    # Multiply Rasters
    global winter
    winter = anthro * conifer

    # Save the output
    winter.save("Winter")

winterHabitat()

# -------------------------------------------------------
# Pre-Breeding

def breeding():
    # Multiply Rasters
    outTimes = winter * lek

    # Save the output
    global Breeding
    Breeding = outTimes.save("Breeding")

breeding()

Comment: That's great news. Can you answer your own question with your updated code for future users with a similar problem.

Comment: Yep, will do, thanks. Trying to debug still so I have the correct syntax. My new error is: breedingPost = winter * lek
TypeError: expected a raster or layer name. I would think Arcpy should know winter is a raster because I just made it from Map Algebra though?

Comment: Make sure you declare (set) the variables outside functions and bring the variables in with the global statement... you should have global winter , global lek in the breeding sub.

Comment: `TypeError: expected a raster or layer name` is because the `winter` variable is `None` not `Raster`. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- [Avoid globals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil) and have your functions `return` results.
- Pass raster variables to your functions.
- Don't mix your script logic and your function defs up. Have the imports and the functions at the top, then the script logic
- Have a `'__main__'` section so you can import your script as a module if you ever decide to.

```
import arcpy

def winter_habitat(anthro, conifer):
    # Multiply Rasters
    outTimes = anthro * conifer
    return outTimes 

# -------------------------------------------------------
# Pre-Breeding

def breeding(winter, lek):
    # Multiply Rasters
    outTimes = winter * lek
    return outTimes 



if __name == '__main__':
    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
    arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.env.workspace = """C:\Users\inputData.gdb"""

    anthro = arcpy.Raster("Anthro_Features")
    conifer = arcpy.Raster("Conifer")
    lek = arcpy.Raster("Lek")

    winter = winter_habitat(anthro, conifer)
    breed = breeding(winter, lek)

    winter.save("Winter")
    breed.save("Breeding")
```

Note that the "winter" variable in your original code is not a raster object as the output from Raster.save(path) is `None`

For example:

```
>>> input = arcpy.Raster('C:/temp/test_raster.tif')
>>> output = input.save('C:/temp/test_output.tif')
>>> print type(output)
<type 'NoneType'>
>>> print type(input)
<type 'Raster'>
>>> print input
C:\temp\test_output.tif
```

Comment: Thank you @Luke . I've posted a follow up question if you happen to have a chance to check it out. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/253370/passing-return-of-if-else-in-one-user-defined-function-to-an-if-else-statement-i